# How can we get the selected check values from the datatable

Tags: jquery, html

I have a datatable with checkbox ,I want the row fields which are selected

How can we get the selected checkbox row values using Jquery

Jquery code for datatable:

```
$.ajax({
                            type:"post", 
                            dataType : 'json',
                            url:"pages/Createkey.php", 
                            data:"adgroup="+grpvalue, 
                            success: function(s) {
                            oTable.fnClearTable();
                            for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

                                oTable.fnAddData([
                                    ("<input type='checkbox' id='checkboxID'/>"),
                                    s[i]['adg']["0"],
                                    s[i]['sta']["0"],
                                    s[i]['cli']["0"],
                                    s[i]['cpc']["0"],
                                    s[i]['con']["0"],
                                    s[i]['ctr']["0"],
                                    s[i]['imp']["0"],
                                    s[i]['ap']["0"],
                                    s[i]['cost']["0"]
                                    ]);


                                    }
                                    }
                        });
```

And my html datatable is:

```
<table id="example3" class="table table-bordered table-striped num-right-alignct">
                                        <thead>

                                            <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th  style="text-align: center;">Key Word</th>
                                                <th  style="text-align: center;">Status</th>
                                                <th  style="text-align: center;">Clicks</th>
                                                <th  style="text-align: center;">Avg CPC</th>
                                                <th  style="text-align: center;">Conversions</th>
                                                <th  style="text-align: center;">CTR %</th>
                                                <th  style="text-align: center;">Impressions</th>
                                                <th  style="text-align: center;">Avg Pos</th>
                                                <th  style="text-align: center;">Cost</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody>



                                        </tbody>


                                    </table>
```

and my table is:
[image]

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle?

Comment: Where you are not understanding the code ,so that I will explain the problem.

Comment: I understand the problem, but i dont have an example to work with

Comment: can you provide json data

Comment: [{"adg":{"0":"Content"},"sta":{"0":"enabled"},"cli":{"0":"85"},"cpc":{"0":"2843765"},"con":{"0":"26"},"cost":{"0":"241720000"},"ctr":{"0":"0.44%"},"imp":{"0":"19404"},"ap":{"0":"1.9"}}]

Comment: For this json data,I have added an extra check box for each row.

Comment: @Shobhan what do you exactly want to do? Do you want to know which checkboxes are checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a unique `id` to your checkboxes (just to differentiate them somehow):

```
...
oTable.fnAddData([
            ("<input type='checkbox' id='row_'" + i +"/>"),// Add unique ID to each checkbox.
....
```

Now, find selected checkboxes and store values of the row in an array:

```
var selected = [];
$('#example3 input:checked').each(function() {
   var $item = $(this);
   var $siblings = $item.parent().siblings();// Assuming the values are siblings of the checkbox parent.
    selected.push({// Store values as objects.
       id: $item.attr("id"),
       keyWord: $($siblings[0]).text(),// Assuming "Key Word" is the first sibling and the value of the field is in the text property.
       status: $($siblings[1]).text(),// Assuming "Status" is the second sibling and the value of the field is in the text property.
       ...
    });
});
```

You'll end up with an array of objects cointaining the fields of the selected rows. Probably you'll have to make some adjustments but I think you got the idea.

Comment: How to access these keyword ,status etc...?

Comment: I'd need to have a look at the tbody of the table to let you know how to access those elements. If the elements are not wrapped (in a div or whatever) this solution should work.

Comment: I have made some changes code that you have provided.Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

A bit modification in @acontell code that solved my problem. Providing the code here, which might help someone.

Add class to your checkboxes:

```
oTable.fnAddData([
        ("<input type='checkbox' id='checkboxID' class='checkboxClass'/>"),
```

Store checked values in an array and remove values when it is unchecked.

```
var selected = [];
$('table#example3 tbody').on('change', '.checkboxClass', function () {

    var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
    // If checkbox is checked then store checkbox value in array
    // If checkbox is unchecked then remove checkbox value from array
    if (ischecked) {
        selected.push($(this).val());
    } else {
        if ((index = selected.indexOf($(this).val())) !== -1) {
            selected.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    // Remove duplicate elements from selected array
    selected = $.unique(selected);
    alert(selected);
});
```